# Definir a versão do aplicativo com o padrão de 4 números

Tags: flutter, versionamento

Uma empresa já possui uma padronização de versionamento de projetos a muitos anos e gostaria de continuar utilizando esse padrão para manter as coisas fáceis no ambiente dela. Esse padrão que foi adotado utiliza a semântica de 4 dígitos como por exemplo `1.5.16.3`.

Tentei aplicar esse padrão a um aplicativo que estou trabalhando para eles e recebi uma mensagem de erro no console do VSCode assim que alterei o `pubspec.yaml` inserindo o valor `version: 1.0.0.0+1`:

```
[AppExemplo] flutter.bat pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in AppExemplo...
Error on line 3, column 10 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version number: Could not parse "1.0.0.0+1".

  ╷

3 │ version: "1.0.0.0+1"

  │          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  ╵
pub get failed (65;   ╵)
exit code 65
```

Tentei pesquisar nas issues do flutter se teria algo que pudesse fazer mas não encontrei nada. Notei que alguns aplicativos instalados no meu celular possuem esse padrão, o que me fez tentar encontrar um meio para que funcione.

Existe algum modo de eu conseguir versionar com 4 números no nome da versão e que valha a pena sem fazer mágica ou esforços hercúleos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do pubspec](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#version):

> A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 0.2.43. It can also optionally have a build ( +1, +2, +hotfix.oopsie) or prerelease (-dev.4, -alpha.12, -beta.7, -rc.5) suffix.

Isto é: neste arquivo obrigatoriamente você deverá usar a notação de três números, com um quarto opcional para o número da build. Isso é necessário para hospedar seu pacote no site `pub.dev` mas não necessariamente para a Google Play Store.

Porém, segundo a [documentação sobre o deploy](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#updating-the-apps-version-number) de apps
na loja, esta configuração pode ser sobrescrita utilizando os parâmetros `--build-name` e `--build-number` passados no momento da build.

Então quando você for buildar seu aplicativo você pode utilizar o comando:

`flutter build apk --build-number=1.2.3.4`

(Uma outra sugestão que pode ser encontrada na internet é modificar o arquivo `local.properties` antes de dar o build, mas toda fez que você usasse o comando `flutter run` suas alterações seriam sobrescritas e você teria que acessar este arquivo de novo. Como este arquivo é preenchido automaticamente pelo Flutter, não deve ser mexido.)

Comment: Bom esclarecimento, me da mais confiança para continuar o desenvolvimento. Eu pensei mesmo que teria que utilizar o `local.properties` como ele vai mudar sempre estou pensando em criar um `.properties` personalizado utilizar ele no `graddle` para controlar o código e o nome da versão. Para o ios, qual é o arquivo equiparado ao `local.properties`?

Comment: No iOS o equivalente é o arquivo ```generated.xcconfig```.

Comment: Dúvidas esclarecidas e agora considero como a resposta válida.